# Is there any way to resume a (long) transaction after the underlying mysql connection has been lost?

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, transactions, database-connection

I have a long running transaction performing a lot of delete queries on a database; the issue is that the mysql connection (to the server on the same machine) will be dropped for no reason every now and then.

Currently, my retry logic will detect the disconnection, reconnect, and restart the whole transaction from the beginning, which may never succeed if the connection's "dropping frequency" is too high.

Is it possible at all to reopen a lost connection to continue the transaction?

I am using MySQL Connector for .NET.

Comment: what is your connection string ? what is your connector/server version? what is the error messages? I think you need to solve the problems.

Comment: Connection string: server=localhost;User Id=root;Persist Security Info=False;database=db;Use Compression=False;port=3307;Default Command Timeout=60. Connector 6.4.4.0, Mysql 5.1. The connection ist just lost ("Connection must be valid and open.").

Comment: Just lost after  60 sec ? after more?

Comment: After a few hours... It is not due to a timeout setting for sure.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is not possible for a Transaction. A transaction is to make sure that either each and every action performed on DataBase is completed or None are.

If your Connection Dropping frequency is too high and you don't have a control on fixing it then what you should do is to make simple queries without a transaction or Better Make the Number of Actions in your Transaction fewer and Send a Batch of Transactions instead of a Single Big Transaction.

And also add some data validation check codes to make sure every thing is right with entries.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically you can do exactly what you need with the XA transactions... but the limitations of mysql are rather drastic and make XA transactions on mysql a joke do be honest: both resume & join on start and end with suspend are not working (since 2006 when this was first released). So to answer you question no! No chance with mysql, forget it! Try increasing timeouts(both on client and server), memory pools, optimize the queries etc... mysql won't help you here.